# Where I can find a open source android apps that have a few performance bugs when run under a few contexts?

Tags: android, performance, open-source, performance-testing

I'm developing an Android Performance Testing Platform which simulates a user context and runs the Application-Under-Test (AUT) and reports the causes and the context of occurrence of any  performance bug i.e. crashing if run on an already loaded CPU/RAM or low network or not responding if the GPS is rapidly being updated or slow response time etc.

So, I've the basic framework ready and now I need apps that have these kind of performance bugs. Can someone tell me if there's any database which maintains bug reports especially performance bugs from opensource/non-opensource android apps? Or you can mention a few apps that're buggy in some certain conditions.

P.S. This is my first major open source project and the first one that I started. Thanks a lot in advance.

I found [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/) but it has performance bugs specific to the phone/OS and nothing much related to the app.

Answer (score 4):

While testing the Google I/O 2013 app with LittleEye, we found that it had a performance bug where it was consuming CPU continuously even when there was no user interaction with the app.

This shows up when the app is opened (and in foreground) and you select a track and then a talk in that track. Opening up any talk will trigger this bug.

There was a similar problem with the facebook app which has been fixed recently (the app would continuously consume CPU while in the background).

Not sure if you are looking for these kinds of bugs, but these are some performance bugs we noticed recently in apps.

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. These're the kind I'm looking for. Do suggest any if you have some on top of your head.

Comment: A few other issues we noticed are with the TweetDeck app that was continuously allocating memory (potential leak), though it was a while back we tested it. Here is a presentation that we did a while back talking about such performance issues (though most related to battery) - http://www.littleeye.co/blog/2013/03/24/understanding-debugging-and-fixing-power-bugs/

Hope this helps!